# How can I update a single React Component from multiple different components?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and still trying to figure out how to plan out and implement some things. I have an app that makes three different API calls and thus three different return values. I'd like to have a global status component that tells me if all three loaded or not. Here's my psuedo code since I haven't found the proper way to do this yet, but this is effectively my train of thought at the moment. I have the main app:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <GenericAPICallerA />
        <GenericAPICallerB />
        <GenericAPICallerC />
        <div>
            <APIStatus/>
        </div>
      </div>      
    );
}
```

This is the APIStatus which just returns if all A, B, and C API calls have loaded or not:

```
class APIStatus extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            aLoaded: false,
            bLoaded: false,
            cLoaded: false,
            
        };
    }

    render(){
        if (this.state.aLoaded && this.state.bLoaded && this.state.cLoaded){
            return <div>Everything has loaded!</div>
        }
        else{
            return <div>Nothing has loaded!</div>
        }

        
    }

}
```

And finally one of the APICaller components. The others are essentially the same:

```
class GenericAPICallerA extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch("example.com/api",{
            method: 'GET',
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) =>{
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                });
            },
            (error) =>{
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: false,
                    error
                });
            }
        )
    }
    render(){
        const { error, isLoaded, profile } = this.state;
        if (error){
            return <div>Errored!</div>
        } else if (!isLoaded){
            // APIStatus.state.aLoaded=false
        } else {
            // APIStatus.state.aLoaded=true
            return(
                <div>Generic Caller A is done!</div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

The comments in the render section are what I don't know how to do. I feel like I should pass in  the APIStatus as a prop to the GenericAPICaller but I'm still unsure how I would update that property from inside the GenericAPICaller.

Thanks!

Comment: You need a shared parent component for your API Callers and your API status. The state will be stored in that component and you can pass it down to your status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function in parent component and pass it to the child will be triggered and pass a state variable to the child where it will be used

For example:

```
import React from 'react'
import ComponentA from './ComponentA'
import ComponentB from './ComponentB'

class App extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
       super()
       this.state = { my_state_variable:`some value` }
    }

    my_function()
    {
        this.setState({ my_state_variable:`new value` })
    }

    render = () => <>
        <ComponentA my_function={my_function} />
        <ComponentB my_state_variable={my_state_variable} />
    </>

}

export default App
```

ComponentA

```
import React from 'react'

const ComponentA = ({ my_function }) => <>
   <button onClick={() => my_function() }>Click Me </button>
</>

export default ComponentA
```

ComponentB

```
import React from 'react'

const ComponentB = ({ my_state_variable }) => <>
   <p>{my_state_variable}</p>
   {my_state_variable === `some value` && <p>if some value this will render </p>}
   {my_state_variable === `new value` && <p>if new value this will render </p>}
</>

export default ComponentA
```

Comment: I like this! I got it working with some minor tweaks. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context` to accomplish this. By using context, you are able to access the value you provide to it as long as the component you attempt to access it through is a child of a `provider`.

The example below illustrates how you can access a shared state between multiple components at different levels without having to pass props down.

```js
const {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  createContext,
  useContext,
  Fragment
} = React;

const MainContext = createContext({});
function Parent(props) { 
  const [state, setState] = useState({child1:false,child2:false,child3:false});
  return <MainContext.Provider value={{state,setState}}>
     <Child1/> {state.child1? 'loaded':'not loaded'}
     <br/>
     <Child2/>
  </MainContext.Provider>; 
}

function Child1(){
  const {state, setState} = useContext(MainContext);
  return <button onClick={()=>setState({...state, child1:!state.child1})}>Load Child 1</button>;
}

function Child2(){
  const {state, setState} = useContext(MainContext);
  return <Fragment>
    <button onClick={()=>setState({...state, child2:!state.child2})}>Load Child 2</button>  {state.child2? 'loaded':'not loaded'}
    <br/>
    <Child3/> {state.child3? 'loaded':'not loaded'}
  </Fragment>;
}

function Child3(){
  const {state, setState} = useContext(MainContext);
  return <button onClick={()=>setState({...state, child3:!state.child3})}>Load Child 3</button>;
}

const el = document.querySelector("#root");
ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, el);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```